# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException json android

Tags: android, json

In the below code I got an error when running my android project for sending json to cloudant.com from second layout,
quiero mandar json desde android en un segundo layout pero me manda el error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException  desde el logcat

```
    //Obtenemos una referencia al LocationManager
    locManager = 
        (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Obtenemos la última posición conocida
    final Location loc = 
        locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



    // buton ejecuta
    btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //  comenzarLocalizacion();



            HttpPost request = new HttpPost( "https://tonatiuhnava.cloudant.com/android/" );
            request.addHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            request.addHeader( "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString( "tonatiuhnava:70n471uh".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
            JSONObject cadena = new JSONObject();

            if(loc != null)
            {

            try{
                cadena.put("nombre", "tonatiuhNava");//Le asignamos los datos que necesitemos
                cadena.put("Category", new Integer(01));
                cadena.put("Event", new Integer(201));

                cadena.put("Fecha",curTime);
                //cadena.put("Fecha",  currentDate.toGMTString());
                cadena.put("longitud", new Double(loc.getLongitude())); 
                cadena.put("Latitud", new Double(loc.getLatitude()));

            } catch ( JSONException e )
            {
                Log.d( "WAZAAA" , "error json" );

            }

            try{
                request.setEntity( new StringEntity(  cadena.toString() ) );

            } catch ( Exception e ){
                Log.d( "WAZAAA" , "error entity" );

            }

            DefaultHttpClient connection = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try{
          Log.d( "WAZAAA" , "haciendo request");

            HttpResponse execute = connection.execute( request );
            Log.d( "WAZAAA" , "request hecho");

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
            int numRead = 0;
            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = execute.getEntity().getContent();
            stream.read( bytes );
            x.append( new String( bytes, 0, numRead ) );



            Log.d( "WAZAAA" , execute.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() );
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e( "WAZAAA" , "client error" );
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e( "Internet Please :..(" , "IO error" );
            }
            Log.d( "WAZAAA" , "fin");

            // termina if 
            }else {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Espere a que cargue coordenadas...";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking requests can not run on the UI Thread, They should run on a separate thread.  Use an AsyncTask. Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: AsyncTask? one example?